# Using php to execute a Postgres query and make the result downloadable

Tags: php, csv, download, postgresql

I got a Query that in one scenario I execute the query and it displays the results in a table format with data and headers etc... The second scenario I want to creat is a direct download link that will execute the query and put the results into a .csv file for saving or opening in Excel.  I have the code for the display already but I am wondering how to make it download for the user.

Here is a tidbit of code for the execute and display.

```
    <?php
    $month = $_POST['mydate'];
    $monthfrm = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($month));
    $monthhd = date("F", strtotime($month));
    $monthto = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$monthfrm . +1 month"));
    $date = date("F j,Y");
    if ($_POST['credsubmit']) {
       print('<head>');
       print('<link href="helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
       print('<link href="dropdown.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
       print('<link href="default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    // Connecting, selecting database
       $dbconn = pg_connect("yeah we all know what goes here");
         if (!$dbconn) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
          }// Performing SQL query
     $query = "
       SELECT cm.\"ID\",a.\"ID\" as \"DDI\",cm.\"Date\",c.\"Amount\",ct.\"Name\" as \"Name\",cm.\"Comments\" as \"Comments\"
       FROM \"BIL_CreditMemo\" cm
       LEFT JOIN \"BIL_Credit\" c ON (c.\"ID\" = cm.\"BIL_CreditID\")
       LEFT JOIN \"ACT_Account\" a ON (c.\"ACT_AccountID\" = a.\"ID\")
       LEFT JOIN \"BIL_val_CreditMemoReason\" ct ON (ct.\"ID\" = cm.\"BIL_val_CreditMemoReasonID\")
       WHERE cm.\"Date\" >= '$monthfrm' AND cm.\"Date\" < '$monthto';
       ";
       $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
       // Printing results in HTML
       echo "<h2 align=center style=margin-top:20>Credit Memo Report for: $monthhd</h2>";
       echo "<table align=center width=60%>\n";
       print('<tr class="trstyle"><td>ID</td><td>DDI</td><td>Date</td><td>Amount</td><td>Name</td><td>Comments</td></tr>');
       while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
       echo "\t<tr>\n";
         foreach ($line as $col_value) {
           echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
         }
       echo "\t</tr>\n";
      }
      echo "</table>\n";// Free resultset
      pg_free_result($result);// Closing connection
      pg_close($dbconn);
      }
      ?>
```

So that is what I got so far and want to make the results a direct download to a csv file?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gaaah. [My eyes! the goggles do nothing!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juFZh92MUOY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a few HTTP headers, then you just echo out CSV data. For example,

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


echo "Name,Favourite Colour\n";
echo "Phil,Blue\n";
?>
```

Note that if you're specifically targeting Excel, then there are libraries that will allow you to create .xls files; I quite like [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.net/)

Comment: Going to go with that phpexcel got it installed and will read up on it for later use because this is going to be a great feature.  Also with the Query I posted above, I get what you are saying, But I guess I would just echo out the query results.  I assume

Comment: Yes, just make sure you set the headers before starting any output, then output data for the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to tell the browser that the output will be an octet stream.
2. Use [fputcsv()](http://us.php.net/fputcsv) to write the results of the query to a temporary file in CSV format.
3. Send the content of the file using [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Alternately, there is a way to make fputcsv() write its data directly to STDOUT, but it'll take a little bit of finagling, but it'll let you skip using a temp file.  Either way, I'd read the examples for readfile() as it'll help you set up the headers to initiate the "file download" that you're looking for.